# Extending Eloquent find

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

This might be a silly question, but as I'm not that familiar with Eloquent I don't really know how to search for it (and all the resources I've got didn't provide me with a way to accomplish what I'm after).

Basically - I'm used to doing something like this in native PHP:

`$dummy = new Model(); $results = $dummy->find(['some criteria']);`

where I could parametrize given criteria based upon given model. In real life scenario I want to find all `Location`s that are within `radius` from `lat`/`lon`.

I know that I can do `Location::where([query here for finding])`, but when `radius` changes at some point, I'll have to find all places where it was used and change it. More elegant solution, for me, would be to do it as:

```
static public function locate($params = array())
{
    $find = self::query();

    if ($params['latitude'] && $params['longitude'])
    {
        // if radius is not given, use radius of 1km
        if (!isset($params['radius']))
            $params['radius'] = 1/111;

        $find->where(DB::raw('SQRT(POW(latitude - '.$params['latitude'].', 2) + POW(longitude - '.$params['longitude'].', 2))'), '<=', $params['radius']);
    }

    return $find;
}
```

And then use it as:

`Location::locate(['latitude' => $lat, 'longitude' => $lon])`

It would be great if I could override the `find`, but I don't think that's easily doable.

But, coming down to a question - how sensible is such approach? Is there a Laravel way of doing what I'm describing?

Comment: That's not what `find` does though. You can override `where` instead. I don't think it's unreasonable, but probably a query scope is better.

Comment: @apokryfos - indeed `find` is the wrong function (in the framework I was using `find` was used to search for objects using criteria, rather that finding object by id as it's done in Laravel). I imagine I could override `query`, but I'm uncertain how it will pan out working with the rest of the framework, as every Eloquent function uses it (?). Still, I'd appreciate some guidelines if it's actually wise to do.

Comment: If you override it for that model your risk is limited only on that model, but as I mentioned in my answer, you are basically limiting what you can do with the model (maybe that's ok for now but maybe that's not ok in the future) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that approach, if you were to override the built-in functions, is that you're completely removing the capability of searching for something by its lon/lat since whenever it's going to be in the condition you're going to search for things within a radius from that lon/lat.

I would personally suggest using a scope:

```
public function scopeWithin($query, $lon,$lat,$radius=1/111) {
     return $query->where(DB::raw('SQRT(POW(latitude - '.$lat.', 2) + POW(longitude - '.$lon.', 2))'), '<=', $radius);
}
```

And use it like:

```
Location::within($lon,$lat)->where(more stuff);
```

Comment: That's exactly it! This solves all of my problems, and I don't really have to extend my function `locate` if I want to add further functionalities as `scope*` will separate them. Thank you very much!